# Execute javascript using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to execute javascript using selenium.

JavaScript code on UI:

```html
<input id="rbSingleFuture" class="rfdRealInput" type="radio" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'rbSingleFuture\',\'\')', 0)" value="rbSingleFuture" name="PaymentTypeGrp" _rfddecoratedid="_rfdSkinnedrbSingleFuture"></input>
```

My code:

```html
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_webDriver;
           js.ExecuteScript("onclick=javascript:setTimeout(__doPostBack('rbSingleFuture',''), 0);");
```

This does not clicks on the radio button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_webDriver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('rbSingleFuture').click();");
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp